# Checking if two divs contain content, and if not adding a class to their container div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check whether two child divs contain content and if they do not ie they are empty then I would like to add a class to their parent div. 
This is my code but this adds the class="noBorder" to the parent div if the child divs are empty or not.

```
if(('div.nav-previous:empty') && ('div.nav-next:empty')) {
    jQuery('div#nav-below').addClass('noBorder')        
};
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Gina

Comment: What I needed was a class added to the parent div ONLY if both child divs were empty. Solved it with some help from some folks here.:)

Comment: You should indicate the best answer for your question by clicking the check mark next to it.  And welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because a jQuery selector will always return a value, regardless of whether it matched anything.

```
$('.this-doesnt-exist') // returns []
```

The above will return an empty array which will evaluate to TRUE.

Whenever you want to check if jQuery has returned a set of elements, you must check the length property:

```
if( $('.this-doesnt-exist').length == 0 ) {
  alert('it didnt exist!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if() statement is nonsensical.  Technically, it is asking

```
if(true && true) {
  //do stuff
}
```

I presume what you want to do is check to see if two elements are in fact empty and then apply a style.  In that case you would do:

```
if($('div.nav-previous:empty').length !=0 && $('div.nav-next:empty').length != 0) {
    jQuery('div#nav-below').addClass('noBorder')        
};
```

The if() statement will now be asking:

1. Are there any `<div class="nav-previous">` that are empty, and
2. Are there any `<div class="nav-next">` that are empty?

If you have more than one nav-previous and nav-next, then this might look different, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: thanks jbrookover. I added the length as you suggested and it worked as I needed it to. Your answer helped my understanding a lot. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing some more investigation: Here is the code that worked

```
if (jQuery('.nav-previous').is(':empty') && jQuery('.nav-next').is(':empty'))       
    {
      jQuery('div#nav-below').addClass('noBorder');     
    };
```

NOTE: :empty selector only works if there are no brs or spaces within the divs.